# Why can't I import Three.js using "import * as THREE from 'three';"?

Tags: three.js, brackets

I am a beginner at three.js and I am following everything it says in the tutorial I am following (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xJAfLdUgdc4&list=PLjcjAqAnHd1EIxV4FSZIiJZvsdrBc1Xho&index=1) I have installed parcel with "npm install parcel -g", and I have installed three.js with "npm install three" and my code editor (Brackets) is throwing two errors for the code "import * as THREE from 'three';".
Under JSlint it says "Expected an identifier and instead saw 'import'." and under ESlint it says "ERROR: Parsing error: The keyword 'import' is reserved"

I copied the code in the tutorial exactly as it said, and it's still throwing those errors. weird
And in index.html I tried making the script tag have type="module" and without it having that, and it still doesn't work.

Maybe it's because I'm not using Visual Studio?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm three.js developer, too.

Perhaps do you miss following section?

```
 <script type="importmap">
        {
            "imports": {
                "three": "https://unpkg.com/three@0.148.0/build/three.module.js",
                "three/addons/": "https://unpkg.com/three@0.148.0/examples/jsm/"
            }
        }
</>
```

If it's wrong, contact me.
Thanks.

Comment: i put it above the <script src="scripts.js" type="module"></script> line and it still dont work

Answer (score 0):

I was building a three.js project and came across a similar problem,I fixed it by reinstalling three.js with the command:

```
npm install --save three
```

and after that, I deleted node modules and npm installed it, in order to refresh and update dependencies in the project's dependencies.
Rerun your app and it should be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the cdn to import it directly like this in your main.ts or index.ts file.

import * as THREE from 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.117.1/build/three.module.js';

If still facing issue, read and follow this medium docs to understand what is the main problem and do the complete setup

Link: https://medium.com/threejs/module-specifiers-versus-relative-import-references-fd747980ba6f

#threejs #three #javascript